# Dask dashboard doesn't show any processing activity until after Xarray datasets are written out

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I have a program that reads in several Xarray datasets, does some merging, reordering, concatenating to produce several merged Xarray datasets, and then writes them out to several files. I read in the datasets with `chunks="auto"` and activate a distributed client at the beginning of the program using `client = Client(n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=16)`.

When I run the program and check the Dask dashboard, nothing really happens except that I can see the CPUs working. No tasks appear on the main timeline, even as I can see my output directory being populated with the resulting files. Finally, after all the files are apparently done processing and being written out (a ~20s process in this case), all of a sudden there is a flurry of activity on the Dask dashboard for about 4.5s, showing a bunch of `open-dataset`, `getitem`, `open-dataset-concatenate`, etc tasks being completed, basically everything I would expect from my processing chain.

But surely these tasks should all be completed *before* the data is all written out to file? I get that dask and xarray do lazy computation but is there any reason this activity would appear *after* the files are written and not before? Or am I possibly doing something wrong?

I post this in the hopes that my situation is known behavior and I don't have to come up with a minimal working example, but I can try and whip one up if necessary.

EDIT:
I see now that if I actually set chunks on the Datasets explicitly rather than with `"auto"`, then Dask starts doing stuff while processing the data. However I still can't figure out what it's trying to do in my original situation.